# Strategy pattern vs Inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

We have some algo to apply over some data, and the algo may get applied multiple times on same data. We have two ways to do this:

1. Keep data and logic seperate

   ```
   class Algo{
   public:
       virtual int execute(data_object) = 0;
   };

   class AlgoX: public Algo{
   public:
       int execute(data_object);
   };

   class AlgoY: public Algo{
   public:
       int execute(data_object);
   };

   class Data{
   public:
       string some_values;
       ...
       void* algo_specific_data; //It will contain some algo specific data (like state of algo)
       Algo* algo_ptr; //Reference of Algo

       int execute(){
           algo_ptr->execute(this);
       }
   };

   some_function(){
       Data* data_object = create_data(algo_ptr, algo_specific_data); //A dummy function which creates an object of type data.
       data_object->execute();
   }
   ```
2. Bind data and logic by inheritance

   ```
   class Data{
   public:
       string some_values;
       ...
       virtual int execute() = 0;
   };

   class DataWithAlgoX : public Data{
   public:
       AlgoX_Relateddata algo_related_data; //some algo specific data (like state of algo)
       int execute();
   }

   class DataWithAlgoY : public Data{
   public:
       AlgoY_Relateddata algo_related_data; //some algo specific data (like state of algo)
       int execute();
   }

   some_function(){
       Data* data_object = create_data(algo_type); //A dummy function which creates an object of type data.
       data_object->execute();
   }
   ```

Which design is better, if

1. We can change algo type between the multiple calls of `algo->execute()` on data 
   (But switching will not be very frequent, and needed only in some specific scenario).
   Some people may point out that switching of algo will make us to recreate the `data_object`.
   We are willing to take that extra burden if architecture **2** is much better than **1**.
2. We will not change algo type ever between the multiple calls of `algo->execute()` on data .

Comment: In option 1, you can thought about using `std::function` instead of classes.

Comment: @Germán For simplicity I have used only one function as `execute()` in `Algo`. There might be multiple private functions in it, which will get called by `execute()`.

Comment: There is no impediment for the function to call other functions ;-) Anyway, it is only an idea to consider. Only you know the specifics of the real problem like how linked are the algorithms to the data or about the necessity of keeping any kind of state.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but have you considered using templates?

Comment: @MikeMB Can you please share some more thought on template thing... or can you write an answer describing the way you are talking about.. Other efficient suggestions are also acceptable here..

Comment: @King: I can, but would probably need to know more about your design constraints, i.e. why you ended up with polymorphism in the first place.  E.g. why it's not possible to just write `AlgoX(data)` or at least `Algo->execute(data)` where `AlgoX` is an implementation of an actual algorithm (like in your first example) and `Algo` is a pointer to a interface with a virtual execute method. If stable ABIs or at least compilation barriers are a concern, templates become much less applicable. Also, is your actual input data (not the internal state of the algorithm) always the same type?

Comment: Oh, and two more questions: why do you have to pack together the algorithm and the data in the first place, instead of the data being a parameter to the execute function and can you use c++11 or later?

Answer (score 1):

Mixing Data and Algorithm in the same class in (very) bad practice.
In breaks the Single Resposability Principle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

If you want to combine multiple types of Data with multiple Algorithms 
use something like a Mediator. The idea is to define Data and Algorithms separately and define the interaction between them in the mediator.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

In my opinion, design 2 is MUCH worse then 1. And even in the case of design 1, I would remove the reference to the algorithm in the Data class. It only introduces High Coupling, i. e. a dependecy between the classes which make one affected bt the changes in the other:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)

(and google "Low coupling, high cohesion", it is another OOP principle).

The Mediator  would solve the coupling problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer keeping Algo separate from Data always. In general Same data could be used for different Algo and same Algo can be used on different Data. So if you are implementing it as an inheritance chances are high that it will lead to code duplication or combinatorial explosion of subclasses like `DataWithAgloA` `DataWithAlgoB`.

More importantly Data provider i.e the system which generates data might not need to know about complex algorithms to be used there. It could be very well dumb system to generate data and there could be researchers who are updating the Algo. Keeping Data and Algo essentially violates `Single Responsible Principle`. Now your DataWithAlgo class has 2 axis of change (As uncle bob would say) from Algo and from Data.

Keeping Data and Algo separate keeps both the code nimble and easy to change and also satisfy `SRP`. This reduce coupling in the code, avoids any combinatorial explosion. So I would always go segregating Algo from Data.

Answer (score 0):

> Strategy pattern vs Inheritance

Between these two, favor the first over the latter. In inheritance, not only are you inheriting the API contract, you're also inheriting *behavior*, which may or may not be possible to override. And in your case, since you state that multiple algorithms may be applied to the same class *today* but not necessarily *tomorrow*, applying inheritance this way will lead to an explosion of classes and duplicate code, as you've shown.

However,

> We have two ways to do this

How come? Have you considered the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) (my favorite)? Depending on how your data nodes are structured, perhaps even the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is a valid choice.

I would also caution against the blanket "mixing data and algorithm **always** breaks `SRP`" advise generally thrown around. You introduce "2 axis of change" *only when the use-case actually arises*. Ideally, if you have perfect encapsulation, there is no reason why a type can't handle and apply algorithms to its own data. This depends on the domain; in your case, this clearly does not (seem to?) apply.